# DOM element to image generates only white image

Tags: javascript, canvas, html2canvas

I'm using [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com)  to create images from the DOM element.

The code looks like this.

```
    const node = document.getElementById('domElement') 
    html2canvas(node, {
      windowWidth: node.scrollWidth,
      windowHeight: node.scrollHeight,
    }).then(canvas => {
      const image = canvas.toDataURL()
    })
```

But its only rendering an image that is fully white. The image size (l*b) is accurate.

[image]

But when I try to render the image of the full body it shows the image but with blank white screen on top.

### i.e. when,

```
    const node = document.body
```

[image]

**How will the elements be added properly and not the blank white screen on the image?**

> The code is inside an antd design modal.

Comment: are the images inside an iframe?

Comment: @cloned no...i'm just trying to get image out of a div..no iframe is involved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement solved my problem.

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0)
```

The final code looks like

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0)
const node = document.getElementById('domElement') 
html2canvas(node, {
  windowWidth: node.scrollWidth,
  windowHeight: node.scrollHeight,
}).then(canvas => {
  const image = canvas.toDataURL()
})
```